How do I run a ts-node/tsx script that imports a file containing `import "server-only"`
I have import "server-only" across my nextjs backend code. server-only uses conditional imports to throw an error if the runtime is not react-server. I need to run an ops script that imports module from my next code that includes server-only, but because the ops script runs as "node" instead of "react-server", I cannot import the code without server-only throwing an error.
How do I run my ops script (ie with tsx) such that server-only does not throw an error in my scripts?
So far I have--

not figured out a way to run a script as react-server (only as node) such that the conditional exports does not throw the server-only error.
forked the server-only package, but I have not found a way to import the package into my project while also preserving the package.json file. As such, it is not respecting the conditional imports and thus throwing an error. (See my question about importing local modules with package.json)

